# calling a variable from outside the function using python

Tags: python

I have this script that allow the user to enter the file name by an argument and then it updates the file version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

class versionBumper:

    def __init__(self):
        self.version = None
        self.SavedBefore = ""
        self.SavedAfter = ""

    def change_version(self, file_to_be_modded, packageVersion):
        for line in file_to_be_modded:
            if packageVersion in line:
                print "VERSION FOUND: ", line
                self.VersionNumber = line
            elif self.VersionNumber is None:
                self.SavedBefore += line
            else:
                self.SavedAfter += line
        file_to_be_modded.close()
        print "Version: ", self.VersionNumber
        return self.VersionNumber

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "sys.argv[1:]:", sys.argv[0:]
    versionBumper123 = versionBumper()
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    path = "/home/Desktop/Crate/Crate/" + filename + "/build/CMakeLists.txt"

    if os.path.exists:
        inputFile = open(path, 'r')

    else:
        print "no match found"
        sys.exit()

    print "Which version number to bump ?"
    print "1) major"
    print "2) minor."
    print "3) patch."

    Choose_version = raw_input("Choose version: ")

    if Choose_version == "1":
        version = versionBumper123.change_version(inputFile, "_MAJOR ")
    elif Choose_version == "2":
        version = versionBumper123.change_version(inputFile, "_MINOR ")
    elif Choose_version == "3":
        version = versionBumper123.change_version(inputFile, "_PATCH ")
    else:
        print "Invalid input. Exiting gracefully..."
        sys.exit()

    outputFile = open (path, 'w')

    splitted_version_line_substrings = version.split('"')

    Version_Name = splitted_version_line_substrings[0]
    Version_Number = int(splitted_version_line_substrings[1]) + 1
    parenthesis = splitted_version_line_substrings[2]

    new_version = (str(Version_Name) + '"' 
                  + str(Version_Number) + '"' 
                  + str(parenthesis))
    print "new_version: ", new_version

    outputFile.write(str(versionBumper123.SavedBefore))
    outputFile.write(str(new_version))
    outputFile.write(str(versionBumper123.SavedAfter))
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled.py", line 57, in <module>
    splitted_version_line_substrings = version.split('"')
NameError: name 'version' is not defined.
```

I also tried to define `version` as a global variable but that also did not work, I can't really figure out how to call `version` from outside the function it is defined in.

Comment: `version` is not defined in a function, it is defined in a class.  Did you mean `self.version`?  Check your indentation.  The `if __name__ == '__main__':` is inside the class, which is rather unusual. `global` should work, although you do't show the code.  It would be better though for the function to `return` the version, rather than using a global.

Comment: no the if __name__ == '__main__' is not inside the class, that was by mistake.  I edited the code

Comment: You need more editing to correct the indentation I think, look after the `sys.exit()`.  Again, `version` is not defined inside a function.  Please clarify which line the error comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Me thinks that you are dealing with a single instance of your class `versionBumper`

```
versionBumper123 = versionBumper()
```

so I *guess* that what you want to do with the statement

```
splitted_version_line_substrings = version.split('"')
```

should be expressed as

```
splitted_version_line_substrings = versionBumper123.version.split('"')
```

Just because you use a single instance of your class, imho you could write simpler code if you don't use a class.